# Storing page properties without database

Tags: php

I have a homepage where I have a number of variables such as a phone number, open times etc and I cant think of  a way to store multiple variables permanently other than in a database and I dont want to make a table just to store 1 row's worth of properties. I was thinking of possibly using a text file but I dont really know.

Comment: There are no other possibilities than: databank, text file, hardcording.

Comment: How many times will you be updating those variables? And how will those updates take place?

Comment: Before coming to StackOverflow, you should have done enough research/work that you've already made a first draft of your code. When you're still in a design phase like this, your question ends up too open-ended/broad to be suitable for a Q&A website like SO - it'd be better to put it on a forum.

Comment: Ive already done a first draft of my code and it seems the people that read the question answered it perfectly fine so I dont see why   this has been put on hold but i've already got my solution so yeah.

Comment: I dont know if people can see this or not but id rather it be not on hold so they can see what do to if theyre in the situation I was in. Theres no point of putting a solved thread on hold if 3 highly repped people will comment on it without having to ask me what i meant in the original question. I dont really care as i've already got my solution but im only saying this for others looking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [PHP's `require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) if you were to store the page information in another PHP file as variables.

This will act like a database (sort of).

If this was your PHP file with your variables (let's call it `a.php`):

```
<?php
    $phoneNumber = "1234 5678";
    $openTimes = "09:00-17:00";
?>
```

You would use `require_once("/a.php");` to utilize the variables in the file and use them like this:

```
<?php
    require_once("/a.php");
    echo "Phone Number: " . $phoneNumber;
?>
```

`require_once` is an *extremely* useful feature of PHP, and can be used for many purposes.

Potential use examples of `require_once`:

- Maintaining a header across an entire website from just the one `header` PHP file
- Connecting to a database where the `require_once`'ed file is situated in a secure non-public area of your website (decreases the chances of someone 'hijacking' your database)
- ***Storing easily-changeable variables where a database is not required.***

Comment: To be fair, this is a better answer that mine if you want a readable file at the end of it, but does result in a very "global"-like scope.

Comment: Actually, you can just do `<?php return ['phoneNumber' => '1234', 'openTimes' => '09:00-17:00'];` and then in the calling code `$data = require 'a.php';`

Comment: @RobBaillie Potentially the file to `require_once` could include a class, of which would greatly reduce the 'global variable-ness' of it.

Comment: Im probably going to end up going this route as I intend on making some sort of install page so they can declare these variables there and change them in the future, thanks.

Comment: @Batzz No problem, that's what we're here for. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the kind of thing that CMS solutions such as Joomla are built for.  As soon as you start going down this route with any decent amount of data you probably want to start looking at something like that.

However, if you really want to, you can go down the route of serialising whatever you want to store and putting it into a text file.

For example, setting it up:

```
$configuration = array( 'PhoneNumber' => '123456789',
                        'OpenTimes'   => 'Monday 9:00 to 12:00' );

file_put_contents( 'configuration.txt', serialize( $configuration );
```

Getting it back out:

```
$configuration = unserialize( file_get_contents( 'configuration.txt' ) );
```

The file can contain much anything - string or objects or whatever.  Just be aware that if you store objects you'll need to ensure that you may need to include their class definition before you re-load them.  And if you store a resource (like a DB connection - I know, unlikely!), you'll need to reconnect or reopen the resource.

Alternatively - if it really is just a series of simple strings, you might want to look at `ini` files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Let's say you have `configuration.ini` file with the content:

```
[address_info]
phone_number = 123456789
open_times = Monday 9:00 to 12:00
```

You can then load it with:

```
$configuration = parse_ini_file("configuration.ini", true);
```

And then reference with:

```
$configuration['address_info']['phone_number']
```

Comment: Id probably go with this one but is this a common way of doing so? I just want to know so I get used to what I should be using instead of what I could be using.

Comment: @Batzz The 'most common' way is the way I outlined in my answer, but I'd say both methods are good to go.

Comment: There are lots of common ways - If it's a very simple sctructure you could also look at ini files - which I have added reference to

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways:

1. JSON

   ```
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'), true);
   ```
2. PHP native serialisation

   ```
   $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('config.bin'));
   ```
3. INI files

   ```
   $data = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
   ```
4. PHP files

   ```
   $data = require 'config.php';

   // config.php
   <?php
   return ['foo' => 'bar'];
   ```
5. XML files, formatted text files, etc.

Each option has its own peculiarities, the native serialisation having the worst possible format to edit by hand. If performance is important and you've picked a format that requires substantial parsing, you will want to have a caching layer to ease the parse time.

**Note**: If you're writing and reading data from within PHP you also need to worry about [file locking](http://php.net/flock).

Comment: Voted +1 for the point about file locking.