# How can I store a small number of properties without using a database?

Tags: php

I have a website written in standard PHP (no framework or CMS) and I have a small amount of information that is configurable that I'd like to store, and I either don't want, or can't store them in a database.

There are:

- Global properties like database usernames and passwords.
- Content like contact phone numbers and addresses.

I know that I could "hard code" such things but I'd like to put them into a file that's not, strictly speaking, "code".

What options are there for storage and which are appropriate when?

Comment: I'm a friend of simple-as-possible, and in this case you don't want to change these values, than a simple file with a large array would totally do the job. This is not very professional for sure, but for quick projects: why not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few options available in pretty standard PHP and the choice depends mainly on the type of information being stored and who is going to edit it.

**"Include" another PHP file that set up variables**

You can use the `include` or `require` keywords to include files that set up a series of variables that can then be referenced outside of that file.

E.g.

database_configuration.php

```
<?
  $dbConfig['host']     = 'myhost';
  $dbConfig['username'] = 'myuser';
  $dbConfig['password'] = 'mypassword';
  $dbConfig['database'] = 'mydatabase';
```

Usage:

```
<?

  include( 'database_configuration.php' );
  $connection = new mysqli( $dbConfig['host']    , $dbConfig['username']
                          , $dbConfig['password'], $dbConfig['database']);
```

This is pretty 'old school' and is how a lot of people would have approached this kind of problem for quite some time.

An advantage is that the configuration is set up using code - you can create whatever you want in this way, and any number of configuration variables / arrays / objects; it's very flexible.

However, it *does* encourage placing variables in what is essentially a global scope, which is not a great idea for future maintainability.

Also, as this is code, it is not appropriate if a non-coder is expected to change the configuration at any point.  It works, but isn't great.

It would also be hard to change the configuration at run-time and then write out the file again.  This makes it essentially read-only when compared to some other options.

However, this is so ubiquitous, it is actually the first example given in the PHP documentation on the function `include`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

**"Include" another PHP file that returns a configuration**

This technique is almost identical to above, though it gets around the problem of introducing a global scope.

Instead of configuring a series of variables, it sets up a local variable that is returned to the including script.

database_configuration.php

```
<?
  return array( 'host'     => 'myhost'
              , 'username' => 'myuser'
              , 'password' => 'mypassword'
              , 'database' => 'mydatabase' );
```

Usage:

```
<?

  $dbConfig = include( 'database_configuration.php' );
  $connection = new mysqli( $dbConfig['host']    , $dbConfig['username']
                          , $dbConfig['password'], $dbConfig['database']);
```

Pretty much the same considerations as the first example need to be taken into account.

It's PHP, so it's very flexible, but it's also very dangerous to hand over to a non-coder.

And you can't get round it - you might have moved the configuration into another file, but strictly speaking it's still 'hard-coded'.

This is also included in the documentation for `include`, as example #5: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Note that both the above solutions can also use `require`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

This is often desirable as you'll get a compile error if the file can't be found.

**Use an `ini` file**

PHP has functions built in to handle `ini` files.  The most useful is probably `parse_ini_file`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

This allows you to create an ini file in a standard format and use that to populate an array.

E.g.

database_configuration.ini

```
[database]
host=myhost
username=myusername
password=mypassword
database=mydatabase
```

Usage:

```
<?

  $dbConfig = parse_ini_file( 'database_configuration.ini' );
  $connection = new mysqli( $dbConfig['host']    , $dbConfig['username']
                          , $dbConfig['password'], $dbConfig['database']);
```

Or, if you wanted to make use of the sections in the file:

```
<?

  $dbConfig = parse_ini_file( 'database_configuration.ini', true );
  $connection = new mysqli( $dbConfig['database']['host']    , $dbConfig['database']['username']
                          , $dbConfig['database']['password'], $dbConfig['database']['database']);
```

This has the advantage of being simpler to read, and therefore, maintain.  It's not PHP code so it's much easier for a non-code to manage.  You still need someone to have access to the filesystem on the web-server, but at least they can't write arbitrary PHP.

A disadvantage is that it can only really handle primitive types.  You can configure arrays, but you can't create objects (like set up a database connection itself).

Finally, like the other examples listed above, it is essentially one-way.  You can't change the contents programmatically and store the results without writing something to output in the `ini` file format.

All said and done though, it IS configuration and so not 'hard-coded'/

**Use a serialised format stored in a file**

There are other formats that you can use to generate more complex objects and which can be more easily generated at runtime.

An example is the simple pair `serialize` / `unserialize`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

You would generate an output by configuring a variable and then outputting a file:

E.g.

```
<?
  $configuration = array( 'host'     => 'myhost'
                        , 'username' => 'myuser'
                        , 'password' => 'mypassword'
                        , 'database' => 'mydatabase' );

  file_put_contents( 'database_configuration.txt', serialize( $configuration ) );
```

Usage:

```
  $dbConfig = unserialize( file_get_contents( 'database_configuration.txt' ) );
  $connection = new mysqli( $dbConfig['host']    , $dbConfig['username']
                          , $dbConfig['password'], $dbConfig['database']);
```

The result is a file that is almost unreadable to the end user, but which can easily be re-generated.  This would make it easy for you to, for example, create an admin screen that allowed such configurations to be set up without access to the file system.

There are quite a few different formats that are supported by PHP, some more human readable than others.

- XML - There are loads of different ways of reading and storing XML files, though SimpleXml is just what it sounds like - simple:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php
- JSON - Initially created for javascript objects, PHP has good support for encoding and decoding JSON objects / arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php
- YAML - Less common, but still of some use, YAML is another human readable markup language: http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php

**Conclusion**

There are lots of different options, and the choice depends on the type of data / configuration being  stored, who is likely to change the configuration and how often it's likely to occur.

My advice would be though, whichever option is chosen you hide it behind a class so that you can change the mechanism as and when your requirements change.

Something along the lines of:

```
 $sUsername = ConfigurationManager::getConfig( 'database', 'username' );
```

And if you have a LOT of content that you're storing I'd strongly urge you look to a standard CMS framework (Drupal, Joomla and the like), or at the very least consider a database...

Comment: I should reference this question and answers (particularly Jack's) for making me want to write a (hopefully) canonical question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249766/storing-page-properties-without-database/27249913#27249913